# How to make a reusable WPF Custom control with data binding properties?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, custom-controls

If I build a custom control with some controls inside it (witch also have some bindings), how can I remove the binding parts from the custom control XAML (like Text="{Binding Path=Name}" and ItemsSource="{Binding}") to make the control reusable? My guess is to create some dependency properties but I don't know how to do this and what makes it harder for me is that some bindings are inside the DataTemplate of the custom control and I can't get the instances by GetTemplateChild().

Here is a my code:

Custom Control:

```
public class CustomListBox : Control
    {
        static CustomListBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox)));
        }
    }
```

Generics.xaml:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
                <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="BindingTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<StackPanel>
     <local:CustomListBox x:Name="BindingCustomListBox"></local:CustomListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs And Person(Sample Data) Class:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person{ Name = "Person1" },
            new Person{ Name = "Person2" }
        };
        BindingCustomListBox.DataContext = PersonList;
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

by removing binding parts I mean moving from custom control to Window.xaml or where ever the user wants to use the control.
I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Take a look at [Control Authoring Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview#control-authoring-basics). Your control should expose (bindable) dependency properties, and the elements in its Template should bind to these properties by TemplateBindings or Bindings with RelativeSource TemplatedParent. However, a custom ListBox should simply be derived from ListBox.

Comment: It seems TemplatedParent is find but I couldn't  make it work yet. Should I create those dependency properties of type String or Binding? can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

And an `ItemsSource` property to your control:

```
public class CustomListBox : Control
{
    static CustomListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox)));
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomListBox));
}
```

Bind to it in your template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
                <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="BindingTextBox" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...and in your view:

```
<local:CustomListBox x:Name="BindingCustomListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" />
```

Comment: Thank you @mm8 . And how can I remove this: Text="{Binding Name}" from DataTemplate controls?

Comment: It depends on what you indend to show in the ListBox. Maybe you should let the consumer of control define an entire `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @amirmola: Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution though not sure if a better one exists(I didn't find any after 3 days). first I added a dependency property (NameBindingStr) to enable users to define the PropertyPath of the binding:

```
public class CustomListBox : Control
    {
        static CustomListBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListBox)));
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameBindingStrProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(
               "NameBindingStr", typeof(string), typeof(CustomListBox),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(""));
        public string NameBindingStr
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameBindingStrProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameBindingStrProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

And the XAML for the custom control:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomListBox}">
                    <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <local:BindTextBox TextBindingPath="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomListBox}}, Path=NameBindingStr, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:BindTextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

for the custom control's items to bind I inherited BindTextBox from TextBox:

```
public class BindTextBox : TextBox
    {
        static BindTextBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BindTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BindTextBox)));
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBindingPathProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(
               "TextBindingPath", typeof(string), typeof(BindTextBox),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextBindingPathChanged)));
        public string TextBindingPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextBindingPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextBindingPathProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void OnTextBindingPathChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            BindTextBox elem = obj as BindTextBox;
            var newTextBinding = new Binding((string)args.NewValue);
            newTextBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(elem, TextProperty, newTextBinding);
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BindTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BindTextBox}">
                    <TextBox x:Name="TemplateTextBox" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The MainWindow.xaml.cs is not changed and I won't type it again(can be found in the question). I have to recall that my goal was to let the user to easily set the binding path. Now the the custom control can be used by one single code:

```xml
<local:CustomListBox x:Name="BindingCustomListBox" NameBindingStr="Name"></local:CustomListBox>
```

Works perfect.